# MUI not working for Sharepoint Online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, multilingual, mui

I'm setting up a site in Sharepoint Online. Some users need translation, so I've tried to enable MUI feature. [I followed the steps here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/03/20/office365-multilingual-content-types-site-columns-and-site-other-elements.aspx).

The alternative languages are checked, user languages are set to an alternative language and even web browser language is set to same alternative language. When logged in as one of the users, I noticed that the "Office365-language" (xxxxxx-my.sharepoint.com) has been translated correctly. However, nothing changes on the site (xxxxxx.sharepoint.com). Have I missed any steps?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas:

1. The Alternate languages is set site per site. Can you confirm that it's present on the `xxxxxx.sharepoint.com` site.
2. Changing your language on your profile can take few minutes.
3. Can you provide more details

Comment: In my experience changing your user profile language in O365 / SharePoint Online can take up to several hours, so be patient. In SharePoint on premises the same changes usually takes only a few minutes as @Merlin says.